# sortrows based on previous sort results

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

Here is the thing

I have a large matrix and I need to sort that based on some columns:

B is the large matrix

```
A=sortrows(B,[1 4 9 10]);%Just a sample input vector
```

Its OK so far.But then in next step (I'm iterating this function) I will need this:

```
A=sortrows(B,[1 4 9 10 16]);%Notice I just add a new column to input vector
```

And same story in next iterations

So my question is can I use previous sort results in each iteration?

Edit------------------------------------

for those who are familiar the main problem is a feature selection task.I have a matrix lets name it IS .You can find one in [here](http://users.aber.ac.uk/rkj/datasets/crisp/mushroom.dat) .In IS rows are objects and columns are features.The task is evaluate a subset of features based on a fitness function .I'm not going in to fitness function because it is not related but as a black-box the input and output are:

```
function fitnessValue=fitness(inputMatrix,featureSubset)
end
```

**inputMatrix must be sorted based on featureSubset** but being sorted based on any permutation of feature set would do the thing

Now main algorithm

```
featureSubset=[];
iter=1;
while iter<iterMax and fitnessValue<1
j=chooseFeature(IS,featureSubset) %select a feature that has not been selected yet based on some parameters 

featureSubset=union(featureSubset,j);%Add j to selected features

IS=sortrows(IS,featureSubset);%Here is the problem

fitnessValue=fitness(IS,featureSubset)
iter=iter+1;
end
```

That's it at each iteration I am adding features one by one and evaluating new feature subset but in order to do that I need to sort the IS matrix based on feature subset .As i said in previous iteration I also sort the entire matrix based on featureSubset(1:end-1) and I belive I can use previous sort result and somehow just sort IS based on current selected feature and get the same result .

P.S **if someone can explain the algorithm of sortrows i would be really grateful**

Comment: Can u provide example of the iteration u use?

Comment: Just to make it clear, when you add column `16` you want rows that have identical values in columns `1, 4, 9, 10` to be sorted "in-place" according to their values in the `16`th column?

Comment: Have you tried a naive implementation using `for`-loop and an incremental sorting?

Comment: I did try almost everything but I'm missing something very clear .I took a look into sortrows source code and I found out it is using something like your suggestion but when I try to make it in two step the result is different

Comment: @Shai And please consider that for my case I just want the sorted matrix based on input vector the sequence does n't matter so any sorting based on any permutation of i.e [1 4 9 10 16] would do the thing.

Comment: @Shai as far as i releaized about sortrows algorithm this two must have the same result :

%C is original matrix
A=sortrows(C,[16 1 4 9 10]);
B=sortrows(C,[1 4 9 10]);
B=sortrows(B,16);
But its not what is your opinion?

Comment: @codedme of course ` A=sortrows(C,[16 1 4 9 10]); B=sortrows(C,[1 4 9 10]); B=sortrows(B,16);` are not the same: `B=sortrows(B,16);` re-sorts all `B` regardless of prevous sort. post some code and show us what exactly is your problem.

Comment: @Shai I edited the question and describe the problem please take a look.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function that I came up with might be useful for someone in future :

```
function [ndx]=sort2(x,cols,oldIndex)

x=x(:,cols);    
[m,n] = size(x);

if nargin<3
    ndx = (1:m)';
else 
   ndx=oldIndex;
end

for k = n:-1:1    
    [ignore,ind] = sort(x(ndx,k));
    ndx = ndx(ind);    
end
```

result--------

```
a=sort2(IS,[1 4 9 10]);
a=sort2(IS,16,a);
b=sort2(IS,[16 1 4 9 10]);

isequal(a,b)=1
```